# Keeping uitableviewcells in a specific order across devices

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a to-do app. Users can create new to-do's and delete them. I also allow users to re-order the `UITableViewCells`. How can I maintain the order of these to-do's across multiple users? I've thought about creating a new column in my SQL data table server side but I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: You have to order your data by something, that sounds like a reasonable approach

Comment: I agree with Paulw11, that seems like a good solution.  But what, specifically, do you need to know about how to implement it?  There are lots of steps involved in maintaining state between users across devices; is there a specific area you need input on?

Comment: Why maintain the order across users? Shouldn't the order be maintained just for a specific user and their devices?

Comment: I think that is a typo @rmaddy - the title mentions multiple devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly you should save the order of the cells on your server (like you said, in your MySQL DB) so that your app on any devices can show proper order everytime fetching latest data.

If you expect something even better, for example updating the order accross the devices in real-time ( show latest order immediately when the user change the todo list on 1 device), please consider using [Remote notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)  (without showing alert) to notify all devices about the changes in the DB.

Happy coding!